# Converting Nested JSON object to Accordion format

Tags: jquery, json, accordion

I have been trying to convert a nested JSON object into the format in which jquery ACCORDION works. I went through many links but couldn't find the proper solution. This is how my JSON looks like:

```
{
  "A": {
    "id": "0",
    "B": {
      "id": "1"
    },
    "C": {
      "id": "2"
    },
    "D": {
      "id": "3"
    }
  }
}
```

NOTE: "B" or "C" or "D" can be further nested too leading to nested Accordion format.

I have tried many approaches but the results are not what I expect. Can any one please help me out.

This is one of my approach which doesn't work :

```
function MakeAccordion(obj) {
    var json = '<div class="accordion">';
    for (var key in obj) {
        if (typeof obj[key] == "object")
           json  = json + MakeAccordion(obj[key]);

        if (typeof obj[key] != "object")
          json = "<h3>" + json + " = " + obj[key] + "</h3>";

       else
          json = json + "</h3>";
    }
    return json + "</div>";
  }
```

Expected Output:

```
<div class="accordion">
  <h3>A</h3>
  <div class="accordion">
    <h3>B</h3>
    <div>id = 0</div>

    <h3>C</h3>
    <div>id = 1</div>

    <h3>D</h3>
    <div>id = 2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

My Output:

```
<div class="accordion">
    <div class="accordion">
        <h3>= 0</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="accordion">
        <h3>= 1</h3>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="accordion">
    <h3>= 2</h3>
</div>
<div class="accordion">
    <h3>= 3</h3>
</div>
```

Comment: What's the current output with your current code?

Comment: I have mentioned my output above now.

Comment: check this  `json = "<h3>" + json + " = " + obj[key] + "</h3>";` it should be like `json += "<h3>" + obj[key] + "</h3>";`

Comment: Still not getting what i expected. I now get this output : https://www.hastebin.com/ufibazebak.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you tagged `jquery` you can use `$.each()` .. something like this

```js
var Json = {
            "A": {
                "id": "0",
                "B": {
                    "id": "1",
                    "K" : {
                      "id" : "5"
                    }
                },
                "C": {
                    "id": "2"
                },
                "D": {
                    "id": "3"
                }
            }
        };

// run a function
MakeAccordion(Json);

// MakeAccordion function
function MakeAccordion(obj) {
  var HTML = '<div class="accordion">'
      HTML += MainAccordion(obj);
      HTML += '</div>';
   $('body').append(HTML);
}

// MainAccordion function 
function MainAccordion(Main){
  var HTML = '';
  $.each(Main , function(key1 , value1){
      console.log(ObjLength(value1));
      HTML += '<h3>'+ key1 +'</h3>';
      HTML += '<div class="accordion">';
      HTML +=  LastAccordion(value1);
      HTML += '</div>'; 
  });
  return HTML;
}

//LastAccordion function
function LastAccordion(nested){
  var HTML = '';
  $.each(nested , function(key2 , value2){
    console.log(ObjLength(value2));
    if(key2 !== 'id'){
      HTML += '<h3>'+ key2 +'</h3>';
      HTML += '<div>id = '+ value2['id'] +'</div>';
    }
  });
  return HTML;
}


function ObjLength(obj) {
    return Object.keys(obj).length;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

[**Final solution**](https://jsfiddle.net/e3tvob47/1/) made by [@Mazhar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6841676/mazhar-mik)

Comment: Thanks for such a quick response. I have a query, what if "B" is further nested ? Will that work ?

Comment: @MazharMIK wait I'll create a full example

Comment: @MazharMIK answer updated.. And No it will not work if there is another nested

Comment: Yes, that's the issue. The problem is that 'B', 'C', 'D' can also be further nested as well. Can you suggest any solution for that. I have been trying it since many days.

Comment: Sure Thanks. @Mohamed-Yousef

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188724/discussion-between-mazhar-mik-and-mohamed-yousef).

Comment: @MazharMIK it'll need a long time to accomplish it .. But I updated my answer with what I'd reached so far .. you can start from it ..

Comment: @MazharMIK you can use `ObjLength(obj)` function I added .. to count the object keys .. and separate the function to keep the code simple to read .. you can use those and you'll get what you want

Comment: thanks for the solution but still it doesn't work and i get this as the result : `<div class="accordion"><h3>A</h3><div class="accordion"><h3>B</h3><div>id = 1</div><h3>C</h3><div>id = 2</div><h3>D</h3><div>id = 3</div></div></div>`

Comment: "K" is missing. Can there by any recursive approach to solve this ?

Comment: @ Mohamed-Yousef , Thanks for the suggestion . I finally got it solved it . Without recursion this couldn't have been solved. Do have a look into my solution [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e3tvob47/1/) . I hope it helps others too. Thanks again for your precious time.

Comment: You're totally welcome @MazharMIK .. Sorry for delay on the reply .. I'm really happy that you did it .. You did a great job man.. Have a great day :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
var obj={
  "A": {
    "id": "0",
    "B": {
      "id": "1"
    },
    "C": {
      "id": "2"
    },
    "D": {
      "id": "3"
    }
  },

   "B": {
    "id": "0",
    "B": {
      "id": "1"
    },
    "C": {
      "id": "2"
    },
    "D": {
      "id": "3"
    }
  }
};

function MakeAccordion(obj) {
        var htmlcode= '<div class="accordion">';
        for (var key in obj) {
            if (typeof obj[key] == "object")
              var subcode=obj[key];
              htmlcode=htmlcode+"<h3>"+key+"</h3>"+"<div class='accordion'>";         

          for(var key in subcode){  
  if(key!== 'id'){  
            htmlcode=htmlcode +"<h3>"+key+"</h3>"+"<div>id="+subcode[key].id+"</div>";
      }
             } 
              htmlcode=htmlcode+"</div>";
        }




           return htmlcode;

    };



var a=MakeAccordion(obj);
 console.log(a);
```

Comment: it doesn't work if the we have further hierarchy in "B" or "C" or "D". I get this result :                                                                                          `<div class="accordion"><h3>A</h3><div class='accordion'><h3>B</h3><div>id=[object Object]</div><h3>C</h3><div>id=2</div><h3>D</h3><div>id=3</div></div>`

Comment: Hi Mazahar i updated  o/p=  <div class="accordion"><h3>A</h3><div class='accordion'><h3>B</h3><div>id=1</div><h3>C</h3><div>id=2</div><h3>D</h3><div>id=3</div></div><h3>B</h3><div class='accordion'><h3>B</h3><div>id=1</div><h3>C</h3><div>id=2</div><h3>D</h3><div>id=3</div></div>

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, unfortunately it still doesn't support nested JSON. I will share the link here when it is solved for any future help for other people who are looking for such a solution.

Comment: You can see my solution here [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e3tvob47/1/) . Thanks a lot for your precious time.